# Normal closure of field extension, axiom of choice

Tags: field-theory, axiom-of-choice

**Update** My previous proof was incorrect. This updated proof is inspired by the comment by 'MartianInvader'.

**Problem** I can prove the statement 'Every algebraic extension $L:K$ has a normal closure $F:L$' by taking an algebraic closure $\bar{L}$ of $L$ (existence needs AC), and letting $F = L(S)$ where $S$ is the set of $\alpha \in \bar{L}$ whose minimal polynomial over $K$ is precisely that of some $\beta \in L$. The $F$ produced this way is normal because it is a splitting field extension of the set of minimal polynomials of $\alpha \in L$ over $K$.

The question is: Is there a proof without taking the algebraic closure?

**Note** $F:L$ is called a normal closure of an algebraic extension $L:K$ if $F:K$ is normal (meaning it is algebraic and the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha \in F$ over $K$ splits) and there are no intermediate fields $M$ between $F,L$ such that $M:K$ is normal (so $F$ is the 'smallest' such).

Also, an extension $F:K$ is normal iff it is a splitting field extension of some subset of $K[x]$.

Comment: Instead of applying Zorn's lemma, can you just take the intersection?

Comment: The existence of the algebraic closure $\bar L$ requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: @MartianInvader The existence of an algebraic closure is proved using AC, and I strongly believe that in fact the existence of algebraic closures for *any* field is in fact equivalent to AC.

Comment: In fact 'algebraic closures exist for any field $\Rightarrow$ AC' is an open problem.  See this MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46566/is-the-statement-that-every-field-has-an-algebraic-closure-known-to-be-equivalen

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: It isn't open at all. We know that the ultrafilter theorem (also Boolean Prime Ideal theorem, and many others) imply the existence and uniqueness (up to isomorphism of course) of algebraic closures. We also know of it to be weaker than the axiom of choice. Therefore assuming the existence, or uniqueness, or both, of algebraic closures will never imply the axiom of choice. Unless ZF is inconsistent, of course.

Comment: How do you define normal closure in this context?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Say that to Donkey_2009, not to me.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: You're the one who strongly believe that asserting the existence (not even uniqueness) of algebraic closures for *any* field is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice. My second comment was directed to the OP.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but your comment begins with "It isn't *open* at all.", which I take as a comment about Donkey_2009's statement about the "open" problem.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: Ah, well. I suppose that I should ping the both of you, then. :-)

Comment: @Donkey_2009: You should read the comments following your last one on this thread. The problem is not open at all (as the link that you have given shows, actually).

Comment: OK, cool.  Sorry for being misleading.

Comment: Are you interested in a particular case, e.g. extensions of $\Bbb Q$, or something like that, or in the general case? My guess would be that given a well-orderable field, then answer should be "Yes, we can prove the existence of a closure without problems" whereas in the general case it might be blatantly false. I might have time during the weekend to try and construct an example (but no promises can be made at this point)

Comment: I have been trying to reconstruct your proof. I would be grateful if you could give me more details. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RodneyColeman Hi, sorry for getting back so late.  Which part of the proof do you want more details on?